# Typeerror: view must be callable

Tags: python, django, typeerror

When I run my server I get a type error message telling me that:

> my view must be callable or a list/tuple

and from what I gathered django version differs and for clarity sake, I am using django latest version... Anyways here's my views.py and urls.py for my project:

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [

 url(r'^login/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.login',name='login'),
 url(r'^logout/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',name='logout'),
 url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',name='logout_then_login'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def user_login(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
  form = LoginForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   cd = form.cleaned_data
   user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],password=cd['password'])
   if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
     login(request, user)
     return HttpResponse('Authenticated  successfully')
   else:
    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')

  else:
   return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
 else:
  form = LoginForm()
 return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
 return render(request,
              'account/dashboard.html',{'section': 'dashboard'})
```

Comment: Provide more details about the error.

Comment: @gonczor here's the actual error....raise TypeError:view must be callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Comment: Yes. In URL patterns, the view must be a reference to the actual view function, not a string. You have strings.

Comment: @Daniel please could you explain with an example,am lost..thanks

Comment: You should read the tutorial for the correct version of Django you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url patterns to below:

```
urlpatterns = [

 url(r'^login/$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.login,name='login'),
 url(r'^logout/$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.logout,name='logout'),
 url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 
    django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login,name='logout_then_login'),

]
```

From the [docs for latest django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url) version, the views are function and not strings.